# Doesn't sh support process substitution <(...)?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

On a Centos 6 machine, this works:

```
bash -c 'if grep -qP --line-buffered ".+" <(tail -n 1000 -F catalina.out) ; then echo "yes"; fi'
```

and this doesn't:

```
sh -c 'if grep -qP --line-buffered ".+" <(tail -n 1000 -F catalina.out) ; then echo "yes"; fi'
```

I get:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `if grep -qP --line-buffered ".+" <(tail -n 1000 -F catalina.out) ; then echo "yes"; fi'
```

Nevermind the grep and tail. The problem is with the process substitution thingy: `<(...)`

Can someone tell me what sh does differently here?

[EDIT]

Thanks for the answers!

The problem arose while using **capistrano** for deployments. It defaults to using **sh** but I changed that to **bash** now.
The reason I couldn't do the normal piping is that when using `tail -F | grep -q --line-buffered`, grep won't exit immediately after a match. There has to be one more edit to the file like `echo "" >> catalina.out` and this was not acceptable in my situation.

Comment: See also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax `<(...)` is only supported by BASH.

For any POSIX shell, use this approach:

```
sh -c 'tail -n 1000 -F catalina.out | if grep -qP --line-buffered ".+" ; then ...'
```

i.e. move the stdin redirection in front of the `if` with a pipe. The `if` will pass stdin on to the `grep`.

`if tail ...| grep` won't work since the `if` won't be able to see it's `then`/`fi` because the pipe separates processes.

Comment: `if tail ... | grep ... ; then ... fi` works for me in dash and bash in posix mode.

Comment: It works in ksh. `sh` on my systems is dash or bash in posix mode.

Comment: @choroba: Interesting. I'm pretty sure it didn't work in Solaris with Korn Shell.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, eh? Using a pipeline in the conditional clause of an `if` statement is supported even in 1970s-era Bourne; I'm certain that every extant release of ksh would have supported it -- and ksh93 supports process substitution, so even the OP's original code would be good there.

Answer (score 6):

You should note that process substitution (`<(...)`) isn't specified by POSIX.  So if you were running `bash` in POSIX mode by invoking it with `sh` or saying:

```
set -o posix
```

then you'd observe errors!

From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode):

> Starting Bash with the `--posix` command-line option or executing ‘`set`
>   `-o posix`’ while Bash is running will cause Bash to conform more closely to the POSIX standard by changing the behavior to match that
>   specified by POSIX in areas where the Bash default differs.
>
> ...
>
> **Process substitution is not available.**

Answer (score 4):

Also take note that *if [Bash is invoked with the name sh](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Invoked-with-name-sh), it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.*

If your sh is actually a link to bash, then this is what's causing that.

Running `sh --version; sh -c ': <(echo a)'` should give you enough info.